# Why is there back slash in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

I just came across this line of code in javascript:

```
Math.round(someVariable\*100)
```

Shouldn't that be simply:

```
Math.round(someVariable*100)
```

I checked and both seem to give me the same results.
Can you thing of any reason why it was coded with a back slash?

Comment: That shouldn't even run. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` is what chrome throws on that line...

Comment: Is that really the **whole** "line of code"?  If so, it doesn't do anything even without the syntax error.

Comment: No it's not a joke and I'm aware that if I copy this code directly to an empty html page it throws an exception. But for some reason it works "fine" within the bigger JS code that it is part of in my project and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Unless that line is somehow surrounded with `/*` and `*/`, that's not valid Javascript :-)

The ECMAScript specification only mentions backslashes in the context of strings (including JSONStrings) and regular expressions. If you use the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo">Click the button.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(2.57\*10);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you'll find that most browsers give an error:

```
Firefox 24esr: SyntaxError: illegal character @ ...
Chrome 31    : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
IE 8         : Invalid character
```

That's all the ones I have on my primary development box.

In fact, since `Math.round()` returns a value that you're supposed to use somehow, that statement is useless even if it *does* work. It may be there's some extra context to this question that you haven't provided.

It *may* be that your particular implementation of the Javascript interpreter is lax with what it accepts, it's hard to discern without knowing the actual interpreter you're using. But, if that's the case, I'd seriously reconsider using it. There are relatively minor differences between implementations but none so far off the mark the they violate the most basic bits of the language specification.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Feel free to cite the ECMAScript section that states that code is valid.

Comment: That's the thing, a lot of lines of code before that line have that back slash in my code and it all starts with this line: var product = price \\* quantity \\* tax_rate; Any ideas on why this line would be causing/allowing me to use back slash later on in the JS code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give us more information, but the reason why i would see * would be escaping a regex *.  Are you sure this isnt a part of some string or regex query scanning something?

And Yes, that would confuse me because any one character would go between Math and round.

This is the only idea i can think of which would have an escaped asteriks (*).